# How to replace string array with array of ObjectIds in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables, `titles` and `members` and I would like to reference id of `title` inside `member`.

My database structure looks like this:

```
// collection titles
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dd5brf45d1320b01edc1432"),
    "name": "mother"
  }
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("3dw5brf45t3320b01edc2864"),
  "name": "wife"
  }

// collection members
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("5rd7tjh23t5786k42edf9753"),
  "firstName": "Mary",
  "familyTitles": ["mother", "wife"]
  }
```

But I would like to replace it to

```
// collection members
{
"_id": ObjectId("5rd7tjh23t5786k42edf9753"),
"firstName": "Mary",
"familyTitles": [ObjectId("5dd5brf45d1320b01edc1432"), ObjectId("3dw5brf45t3320b01edc2864")]
}
```

This is the script that I tried:

```
db.members.find({}).forEach((member) => {
  member.familyTitles.forEach((familyTitle, i) => {
    var titleId = db.titles.findOne({name: familyTitle});
    member.familyTitles[i].update({$set: {i: titleId._id}})
  })
})
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: member.familyTitles is undefined`.

--- EDIT 1 ---

I tried to modify my script as follows:

```
var members = db.members.find({});

if (members) {
  members.forEach((member) => {
    if (member.familyTitles) {
      member.familyTitles.forEach((familyTitle, i) => {
        if (familyTitle) {
          var titleId = db.titles.findOne({name: familyTitle});
            db.members.update({_id: member._id}, {$set: {"familyTitles.$": titleId._id}});
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

It runs it but it without errors but it doesn't make any changes.

Comment: `find()` and `findOne()` is async so you need to await it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
 db.titles.findOne({name: familyTitle}).then(title => {
        db.members.update({_id: member._id,familyTitles:title.name }, {$set: {"familyTitles.$": title._id}});
  }
```

`findOne` - this is `async` method so you can get the result by using `then` method or you can use `await`(async_await.js) operator to get the result once the operation is completed.

`familyTitles:title.name` - you must specify the exact matching value for the array values in the query to update.

Referral links:

[mongodb-javascript](http://zetcode.com/javascript/mongodb/)

[Update Values in an Array (`<array>`.$)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. What I ended up doing was creating a new array, push the values inside and then replace the whole value of `familyTitles` with the new array that contained ids.